# Using BeautifulSoup to parse by id

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

In the BeautifulSoup, version bs4 documentation http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

an HTML document is listed:

```
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""
```

We often extract all the links using the , e.g.

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

outputting

```
http://example.com/elsie
http://example.com/lacie
http://example.com/tillie
```

Within the HTML document itself, these links are listed under the class "sister" and with `id` tags,

```
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">
```

In actual websites, I notice these `id` tags are often a list of numbers, e.g. `id="1"`. Is there a way to parse an HTML document using the `id` tags alone? What would be the preferred way to do this?

First, you could get all tags within the class "sister", i.e.

```
soup.find_all(class_="sister")
```

And then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to solve it with `find_all()`, you may use a *regular expression or a function*:

```
soup.find_all("a", id=re.compile(r"^link\d+$")  # id starts with 'link' followed by one or more digits at the end of the value
soup.find_all("a", id=lambda value: value and value.startswith("link"))  # id starts with 'link'
```

Or, you can approach it with a *CSS Selector*:

```
soup.select("a[id^=link]")  # id starts with 'link'
```

Comment: @alexce One problem I run into is that if I use regular expressions, it returns all id's that start with my regular expression. 
Let's say I only want to find a particular link, link3. How much I do this? soup.find_all("a", id=re.compile(r"^link\d+$")  returns everything beginning with "link"

Comment: @ShanZhengYang well, if you need `link3` only, there is no need in regular expressions: `soup.find_all("a", id="link3")`.

Comment: @alexce Of course, or `soup.find_all( id = "link3")`. Thanks